# Qual è il significato giusto delle espressioni "lunedì questo" e "lunedì prossimo"?

Tags: word-meaning

Supponiamo che oggi sia mercoledì.

1. Vorrei sapere se il significato di "lunedì questo" è:

   - il lunedì di questa stessa settimana
   - il lunedì della settimana prossima
2. Inoltre vorrei sapere se il significato di "lunedì prossimo" è:

   - il lunedì della settimana prossima
   - il lunedì che segue il lunedì delle settimana prossima

Ho fatto [la stessa domanda](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53291/the-expressions-this-monday-and-next-monday/53309#53309) a riguardo dell'uso di queste due espressioni sul sito Stack Exchange English Learners dove ho ottenuto delle risposte pertinenti al loro uso in lingua Inglese. Mi domando se in italiano queste espressioni seguano un significato più rigido / meno flessibile che in Inglese, o se le stesse ambiguità esistono anche in Italiano.

Comment: Il tuo esempio con “lunedì prossimo” menzionato di mercoledì è meno ambiguo, per esempio, del caso inverso: se dici “mercoledì prossimo” di lunedì, alcuni intenderanno veramente il mercoledì prossimo (venturo), cioè due giorni dopo, mentre altri intenderanno “mercoledì della settimana prossima”, cioè nove giorni dopo. (Nel tuo caso, invece, il vero lunedì prossimo e il lunedì della settimana prossima coincidono.)

Comment: Dalle mie parti (Romagna) l'ambiguità è totale, dipende dalle singole persone con cui si parla. Sempre meglio specificare una data, se si tratta di giorni.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

La mia esperienza è che ci sono (almeno) due categorie di persone: quelle che con "prossimo" intendono realmente "il prossimo", ossia il primo che verrà cronologicamente, e quelle che differenziano tra "questo" (il più vicino cronologicamente nel futuro) e "il prossimo" (il seguente a "questo").

Un comunissimo esempio di questa dicotomia si può osservare in un qualsiasi autobus, in cui si possono sentire dialoghi (secondo me molto surreali, ma autentici) come il seguente:

```
A: Mi scusi, scendo alla prossima fermata.
B: A questa o alla prossima?
A: No, a questa.
```

Una simile confusione è possibile anche in altri contesti, come appunto quello del tuo esempio in cui si parla di date o giorni della settimana. Generalmente il contesto dovrebbe chiarire, ma non è infrequente dover chiedere espressamente ulteriori dettagli per eliminare i dubbi. Se vuoi evitare malintesi puoi aggiungere il giorno del mese:

> **Lunedì prossimo 12 febbraio** ...

**Edit**: Come giustamente ricorda @DaG, anche il momento in cui "lunedì prossimo" viene menzionato è importante. Se oggi è martedì o mercoledì e dici "lunedì prossimo", è praticamente certo che tutti penseranno al lunedì seguente, però se oggi è venerdì, sabato o domenica, è molto più probabile che l'espressione "lunedì prossimo" venga interpretata differentemente da differenti ascoltatori o lettori.

---

Un'ulteriore complicazione, nel caso dei giorni della settimana, è che "questo" si può usare anche per riferirsi al passato per indicare "l'ultimo" (il più vicino cronologicamente nel passato). In questo caso le possibilità di confusione sono limitate, in quanto il tempo del verbo sarà differente:

> **Questo lunedì sono andato** ... (chiaramente si parla del lunedì passato)
>
> **Questo lunedì andrò** ... (è nel futuro)

Per evitare qualsiasi ambiguità puoi usare "scorso", che se usato dopo una indicazione temporale si riferisce inequivocabilmente al passato:

> **Lunedì scorso sono andato** ...

Comment: Io ho sempre avuto la sensazione che l'uso di "prossimo" per indicare il successivo al prossimo in senso proprio (e dunque l'uso di "questo" per indicare il prossimo in senso proprio) sia un toscanismo. La conversazione in autobus è surreale, ma del tutto verosimile!

Comment: L'uso di "prossimo" è sempre fonte di gran confusione. Per evitare fraintendimenti io stesso sono solito dire frasi come "lunedì prossimo, non questo, quello dopo", il che è privo di senso dato che "prossimo" dovrebbe essere inteso come "il più vicino"... bella lingua l'italiano.