# Use of "prossimo" instead of "questo" referring to a timeline

Tags: grammar

Today is 7th June 2017. Consider the following phrase

> Questo sabato andiamo al mare

"This" Saturday is definitely interpreted by everyone as the 10th of June.

Now consider the following

> Sabato prossimo andiamo al mare

"Next" Saturday is often both interpreted (by many speakers) as either the upcoming 10th Saturday or the one "next" to the upcoming (the 17th).

I really had troubles misunderstanding sentences like the second because the speaker meant "weekend of the next week" or "monday of next week" according to the specific context.

There is a hint that if the "next" day can be tomorrow or 8 days later, "next" mean 8 days later when talking about a weekday.

> A giugno "prossimo" scadono gli interessi / Il "prossimo" giugno scadono gli interessi

The above can mean June 2017 if said in March 2017, but I found it being interpreted as June 2018 if the sentence is said in May 2017

What is the official grammar interpretation for "prossimo" when referring to a timeline?

Comment: Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5288/707.

Comment: Let me add to the answer that the original, etymological meaning of *prossimo* is “closest”, so *sabato prossimo* shouldn't possibly be ten days in the future or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following extract from the Accademia della Crusca says:

"*The adjective "prossimo" used  with time units (names of months and days of the week) indicates the first unit of time after the enunciation. This means that the month or day referred to in the sentence is the first to come from when I pronounce the sentence; If, for example, today is Wednesday, by  "Sabato prossimo," I am referring to Saturday that comes three days later, that is Saturday of the current week.*"

Il seguente articolo dell'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/prossimo-unit-temporali) chiarisce l'uso di "prossimo" riferito ad unità temporali. Nota inoltre che l'influenza  della lingua Inglese con la distinzione tra "this e next"  possa a volte creare fraintendimenti anche in italiano:

> - ***L'aggettivo prossimo unito ad unità temporali (nomi dei mesi e dei giorni della settimana) indica la prima unità di tempo successiva al momento dell'enunciazione***.
> - ***Questo significa che il mese o il giorno cui si fa riferimento nella frase è il primo che arriva rispetto al momento in cui pronuncio la frase; se, ad esempio, oggi che è mercoledì dico "sabato prossimo", mi riferisco al sabato che viene tre giorni dopo, al sabato della settimana in corso*** Se la stessa frase la pronuncio di sabato, farò riferimento al sabato successivo, cioè a quello che verrà sette giorni dopo. Quando l'unità temporale considerata sia la settimana, vale lo stesso criterio per cui la settimana in corso è quella che contiene il giorno in cui sto parlando, la "settimana prossima" è quella successiva (dopo la domenica della settimana in corso): se ad esempio oggi, mercoledì 5 novembre dico: "ci sentiamo giovedì della prossima settimana" non intenderò ovviamente "domani", ma giovedì 13 novembre (da notare che invece "giovedì prossimo" in questo caso è domani).
> - ***Questo uso particolare vale per tutti gli aggettivi deittici del tipo "prossimo", "scorso", "questo"*** congiunti a unità di tempo posizionali, cioè che si definiscono rispetto alla "posizione" dei partecipanti allo scambio dialogico nel tempo.
> - ***L'incertezza nella scelta di questo aggettivo può essere favorita dall'influsso dell'inglese in cui vengono distinte le unità temporali più o meno vicine attraverso la scelta di this o next***: "this Friday" è "questo venerdì", quello della settimana in corso, mentre "next Friday" è il "prossimo venerdì" quindi quello della prossima settimana. Anche l'italiano offre la possibilità di scegliere tra "questo" e "prossimo", che però assumono lo stesso valore che hanno nell'inglese soltanto quando siano usati contestualmente, contrapposti l'uno all'altro: se oggi (martedì) dico "questo venerdì non posso, ci possiamo vedere venerdì prossimo" intendo che sono impegnata il primo venerdì che viene, mentre sono libera il venerdì della settimana prossima; ma se dico semplicemente "ci vediamo venerdì prossimo" o "ci vediamo questo venerdì" le due frasi sono perfettamente sinonimiche.